# How to be explicit about imports but keep prefix syntax?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I read [here](https://javascript.info/import-export) that `import * as blah from 'blah'` is not the best idea because it imports *everything*, which can bloat your JS files. I presume because Javascript isn't typed the unused functions are difficult to optimise away.

Firstly, is this true, or should I not worry about this as "webpack" (which I think is the thing that builds my React app) will just remove all the unused functions?

And secondly, if I really should avoid `import * as blah from 'blah'`, how can I change this so that I only import the functions I need without refactoring all my code? I'd prefer to keep the `blah.???` syntax, but `import { alice, bob } as blah from 'blah'` doesn't work and `import { alice, bob } from 'blah'` breaks all my code that was previously referring to `blah.alice` but now just be changed to be just `alice` only (I actually prefer the prefix syntax for this collection of functions).

Answer (score 1):

The best thing I can think of is to make your own object and make sure to keep it in sync with the imports

```js
// blah.js
const alice = () => "alice";
const bob = () => "bob";
const charlie = () => "charlie";

export { alice, bob, charlie };
```

```js
// index.js
import { alice, bob } from "./blah";
const blah = { alice, bob };
// Even better, do this:
// const blah = Object.freeze({ alice, bob });
// to avoid accidentally rewriting the methods

console.log(blah.alice());
console.log(blah.bob());
```

You can see this working in a [CodeSandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/blue-tdd-lrq85?file=/src/index.js)

This is definitely the simplest solution, though probably not the best. However, it does get the desired result.